# GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount causes exception

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm learning Firebase (now I have problems with Firebase OAuth). Now I have some problems. The application crashes on the line - `account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(MainActivity.this);` and `mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);` and `Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);` and doesn't throws any exceptions.

Sendind full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SignInButton mSignInButton;
GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("token")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    mSignInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(view -> signIn());
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 1);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    GoogleSignInAccount account = null;
    account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(MainActivity.this);
    if (account != null) Toast.makeText(this, "roe[gerogk[gv", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
    }
}
}
```

01.02.2022 - adding LogCat stacktrace of the error:

```
2022-02-01 20:14:50.150 20929-20929/com.example.stocks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.stocks, PID: 20929
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient: int com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.zzaar() failed to verify: int com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient.zzaar(): [0xF] 'this' argument 'Reference: com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability' not instance of 'Precise Reference: com.google.android.gms.common.zze' (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient' appears in /data/app/com.example.stocks-zfiocw-jpuLL4H5NG87Syw==/base.apk)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getClient(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.stocks.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3286)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3460)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2047)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
2022-02-01 20:14:50.182 20929-20929/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20929 SIG: 9
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: thanks, I added stacktrace log to the question